# Shisha Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

יוסף & אהב אביהם מכל = 156

Comment: Cute! Is that mentioned in the sources anywhere, or is it your own discovery?

Comment: saw somewhere. do not remember where.

Answer (score 3):

Terach as 156 when Yishmael was born.

[Terach was 70 when he begat Avraham.

Avraham was 86 when he begat Yishmael.]

Answer (score 3):

The [Gematria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) of "Yosef" is 156 (also [noted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4972/2) by Gershon Gold). Accordingly, in the book *[Kol HaTor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_HaTor)* on the Redemption, by Rabbi Hillel Rivlin of Shklov, a disciple of the Vilna Gaon, there are [156 teachings](http://www.yedidnefesh.com/kaballah/kol-hator/1.htm) about [Mashiach ben Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messiah_ben_Joseph).

Answer (score 2):

As most people have noted 156 = Yosef
What most forgot is that the Midrash (Tanchuma VaYeshev 18) says that "All that happened to Yosef, happened to Tzion".
All the sefarim bring that Yosef = Tzion =156
Other allusions to Yosef and this number are Kinnah (jealousy- the brothers had for him), Pius (appeasing- what the brothers had to do when he ruled in Egypt), Kiyum (sustaining- as Yosef sustained the world in Egypt, see Parshat VaYechi 47 12), Lev Yochanan (the heart of Yochanan, as it is known that Rabbi Yochanan of the Talmud was a reincarnation of Yosef see Brachot 20a, and sefer hagilgulim if I am not mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

6 x Hashems name = 156

Comment: ...which indeed some sefarim relate to the gematria of Yosef, as in your other answer.

Comment: Yosef was the Midah of Yesod. Yesod is the sixth Midah. Chesed, Gevura, Tiferes, Netzach, Hod, Yesod.....